# Receiving UDP packets at high frequency : packet loss?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio, wireshark

I have a C++ application which uses a UDP Server (using Boost.Asio) that receives packets from a gigabit local network device at a high frequency (3500 packets per second). Some users report a few packet losses. So in the end I chose to run in parallel WireShark and my application to check if there are any packets that WireShark is able to receive but not my application.

What I found is that WireShark does not receive every packet, it seems that it misses some. My application misses also a few more frames that Wireshark received correctly.

**My questions** : Is it possible WireShark gets packets that my application does not ? I thought maybe WireShark has low-level access to the IP stack and packets are discarded by the OS even if they are shown in WireShark ?
Is it possible that the operation in (1) takes too much time such that the next `async_receive_from` is called too late?
I would like to have opinions on this subject. Thanks.

Here is the code I use (quite basic). udp_server.h :

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <fstream>

const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 65537;

using boost::asio::ip::udp;

class UDPServer
{
public:
    UDPServer(boost::asio::io_service& ios, udp::endpoint endpoint)
        :m_io_service(ios),
        m_udp_socket(m_io_service, endpoint)
    {
        // Resize the buffer to max size in the component property
        m_recv_buffer.resize(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

        m_output_file.open("out.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

        StartReceive();
    }

public:
    void StartReceive()
    {
        m_udp_socket.async_receive_from(
            boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer), m_remote_endpoint,
            boost::bind(&UDPServer::HandleReceive, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

private:
    void HandleReceive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::message_size)
        {
            // Write to output -- (1)
            m_output_file.sputn(&m_recv_buffer[0], bytes_transferred);

            // Start to receive again
            StartReceive();
        }
    }

    boost::asio::io_service&    m_io_service;
    udp::socket                 m_udp_socket;
    udp::endpoint               m_remote_endpoint;
    std::vector<char>           m_recv_buffer;
    std::filebuf                m_output_file;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include "udp_server.h"

const unsigned short PORT_NUMBER = 44444;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint endpoint(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), PORT_NUMBER));
    UDPServer server(ios, endpoint);
    ios.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"How is it possible"_: packets can be (will be) buffered on the physical card, if the card runs out of buffer space because packets are not being processed fast enough then they will be discarded.  Differences in applications will mean that different packets get missed.

Comment: UDP is unreliable. You have to layer something on top of it to deal with lost packets etc

Comment: Also, why `std::filebuf`? It's not intended to be used that way. Just `std::ofstream` (possibly turn off `stdio` sync).

Comment: UDP is specifically a connectionless, unreliable, fire-and-forget protocol. You _will_ lose some UDP datagrams, and by using UDP, you accept that fact. You either need to deal with data loss, or you need to use a reliable protocol.

Comment: Your code is completely unoptimized. For example, do you really need to call `bind` once per packet received? Do you need to call `sputn` after each packet? Do you need to wait for `sputn` to return before calling `async_receive_from`? Optimizing it will help. But no matter what you do, you will sometimes drop packets, duplicate packets, or receive packets out of order. If you can't handle that, don't use UDP.

Comment: @black : `std::filebuf`because it is the fastest I have ever tried in my benchmarks a few years ago. I compared `std::ofstream` in text and binary mode and `std::filebuf` was really the fastest of all by a large margin. Anyway, in my real code, I use another processing code that does something else, I am not writing to a binary file. That's just for debugging here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible that WireShark get a packet and that my application
>   does not ?

Yes.  In particular, each socket has its own fixed-size incoming-data buffer, and if, at the moment the kernel tries to add the new incoming packet to that buffer, the buffer doesn't have enough available space to hold that packet, then the packet will not be added to the buffer, and so the application reading incoming data from that socket will not receive it.

Given that, it's entirely possible that WireShark's buffer had room to accept the incoming packet, but your own app's buffer did not.

Comment: Is there any risk to increase the size of the receiving socket's buffer? For example, `m_udp_socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size(1000000))` will set a 1MB buffer. Can this only be good or is there any downsides ?

Comment: The only downside AFAIK is that it will use up more RAM (per socket) than it would otherwise.  Whether that's a significant problem or not will depend on how many big-buffered sockets you want to have open at once, and how much spare RAM is available on your machine :)

Answer (score 1):

How much bytes in a packet? You make a buffer as 64K, let the size be 32K. Then `3.5k * 32k` means 112MB/s, I don't think a gigabit network afford it. And, you write packets to a file, the `sputn` may block you from receiving more packets, consequently the buffer of the driver overflowed, packets discarded.

Comment: 1400 bytes per packets, so below the MTU size. It gives about 5MB/s, but at a very high frequency. Without any buffering on my application, it is quite demanding I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.

If you want to *fix* or *improve* this, rather than just ask about it, use a *much* bigger socket receive buffer than the default, as big as the platform will allow, and make sure your writes to the file are also buffered, with as large a buffer as you can afford given whatever your requirements are about data loss on crash.

Comment: even in that case, you'll lose packets... later, but you'll lose them. Packets are lost as a side effect of the buffer filing process.  The buffer is there to absorb the fluctuations of packet cadence, but not a steady flux of packets that fills a buffer.  And this doesn't take into account noise errors at the wire level, or other means. Enlarging the buffer size is not the solution here.

Comment: @LuisColorado It is part of the solution. The other two parts are to make the reading process as fast as possible, by buffering the writing to the file, which I also mentioned, and to accept that there will always be some packet loss.

Comment: That's not part of the solution anyway.... enlarging the buffer size is a delaying the problem to see if it vanishes (or burying the head in ground to avoid fear) or not.  Read some queue theory and you'll get to this.  If the amount of data incoming is larger than the rate at which you can process it, the mean size of the queue will grow without limit (it's an unbounded linear operator, believe me or not)